# How to test web service with authentication using JMeter

Tags: web-services, authentication, soap, jmeter, load-testing

I'm using **Apache JMeter 2.11** to test a web service with authentication. For the sample request I'm using `View Results Tree` as a listener and a `SOAP/XML-RPC Request` with the following syntax to my parameters:

- **URL**: http://www.domain.com:####/dir/dir/webservice.asmx
- **SOAPAction**: http://www.domain.com/action

### What I have tried

**1) Adding an `HTTP Header Manager` using**

- **Name**: Authorization:
- **Value**: Basic [Base64 code encoded in ASCII, UTF-8, with or without domain in the user name] as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560494/jmeter-basic-authentication)

With result: `Response headers: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized`

**2) Adding an `HTTP Authorization Manager` using**

- **Base URL**: http://www.domain.com:####
- **Username**: [USERNAME]
- **Password**: [PASSWORD]
- **Domain**: [DOMAIN]
- **Realm**: [NULL]
- **Mechanism**: [BASIC_DIGEST/KERBEROS] as explained [here](http://charithaka.blogspot.com/2012/01/soap-with-http-basic-auth-using-apache.html)

With result: `Response headers: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized`

I also tried enabling `Keep Alive` in the request as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130415/secure-webservice-ntlm-jmeter)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to know the auth type, is it basic ? Digest ? Kerberos or other ?

Second, don't use SOAP/XML-RPC Request, use Http Request,

See Templates > Webservice in jmeter menu, it creates a sample test plan for Soap testing.

Add then your authentication with the correct Auth Manager using HttpClient 4 as sampler implementation and check.

Comment: The authentication type is Kerberos. I accesed the SOAP WebService Test Plan via File > Templates... but all documentation seems to work with an older version of Jmeter; for example, I could not find a method parameter in the "Http Request Defaults" screen, or a way to post a SOAP body

Comment: This template shows you hiw to configure the plan, you paste the xml (soap format ) in the raw poSt body of http sampler, any http header goes in Header Manager , same for optional  Soap Action. Show your config with xml rpc , i will give you the config with http sampler.

Comment: See this for an example http://blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter, read after Let's try Post

Comment: In the end it was me confusing "Samplers > HTTP Request" with "Configuration Elements > HTTP Request Defaults" but to avoid authentication at all, I managed to get another version of the web service without authentication. Thanks for all your feedback.