# Web Service Call for creating a directory in SharePoint?

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, wsdl, directory

What webservice call creates folders/directories (and sub directories)?

I looked at the list of methods [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists_members.aspx) (and in the list of calls I retrieved from [SOAP_UI](http://www.soapui.org/)/[Burp Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914899/testing-webservice-with-soapui-windows-authentication) from the lists.aspm?wsdl file.

I'm looking to programmaticly duplicate the functionality of a user:

1. Logging into SharePoint using the Web Interface
2. Entering a specific list.
3. Clicking the new folder/directory button and naming the new directory something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Lists.UpdateListItems for this. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.updatelistitems(v=office.12).aspx for examples.