# Is it possible to use SoapUI for testing services secured with SPNego?

Tags: web-services, http, authentication, soapui, spnego

I have web service secured with SPNego (HTTP challenge returns WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate). This security mode is also referred as Windows integrated authentication. Is it possible to use SoapUI to test this service? It looks like SoapUI (4.0.0) ends communication once it gets challenge 401 HTTP response instead of following negotiation algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please see answer to the same question here:

[Testing web service with SoapUI and Windows authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/914899/testing-webservice-with-soapui-windows-authentication)

working solution is to use proxy for adding Windows authentication headers to your requests